# How to order mysql results in the order I specify the row id's inside the "IN" condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The query is:

```
   SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `stockid` IN (33, 12,53,4,99,88)
```

But when I run the query it doesn't return the rows in the order of 33, 12, 53 etc

I am using php. The above is a simplified example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use order by field

```
SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `stockid` IN (33, 12,53,4,99,88)
order by field(stockid,33, 12,53,4,99,88)
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me SELECT * FROM [OrderDetails] where productid in (11,72,42,14) order by field(productid,11,72,42,14) -> Error 1 could not prepare statement

Comment: Add the complete code its related to prepare statement not query. Run this query in DB and will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a temporary table with two column ('stockIdColumn', 'orderColumn').

```
| STOCKID | ORDER |
|      33 |     1 |
|      12 |     2 |
|      53 |     3 |
|       4 |     4 |
|      99 |     5 |
!      88 |     6 |
```

Join this table with your and order by column [ORDER]

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stock s JOIN temp t ON t.stockId = s.id
ORDER BY t.order
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that it's really answer, but it another way:

```
SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (33)
UNION SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (12)
UNION SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (53)
UNION SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (4)
UNION SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (99)
UNION SELECT * FROM stock WHERE stockid IN (88)
;
```